# Update data in database with pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I recently made a CMS with mySQL and PDO following a video tutorial from PHPAcademy on youtube.

I want to add an edit function to it though.

I have the page done, but not the PHP to update the data.

So, I'm wondering, how would I update data in the database with PDO and save the new data?

I have this:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE articles 'article_content'=? WHERE 'id' = ?");
$query->bindValue(1, $_POST['content']);
$query->bindValue(2, $_POST['id']);
$query->execute()
```

;

Comment: You have to use a *correct* SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

```
"UPDATE articles SET  `article_content`=? WHERE `id` = ?"
```

One you are missing SET.

Two you are using single quotes for column names;use backticks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the keyword **`SET`** in your query

It should be

```
$pdo->prepare("UPDATE articles SET `article_content`=? WHERE `id` = ?");
                           ----^
```

Comment: oh, I'll add that later when I get home.